# Strange variable NGREPEAT_SOURCE_RE

Tags: angularjs, var

I came a cross this line of code in a fiddler. I have never seen this before, can anyone explain what exactly it is doing and why the var NGREPEAT_SOURCE_RE = a comment?

Thank you!

```
var NGREPEAT_SOURCE_RE = '<!-- ngRepeat: ((.*) in ((.*?)( track by (.*))?)) -->';
```

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/g/3SH7a/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like that code is a regular expression designed to match the default comment angular puts in to the html when expanding an `ng-repeat`:

```
<!-- ngRepeat: <item> in <iterator> track by <someUniqueProp> -->
```

Where `<iterator>` and `track by <someUniqueProp>` are optional, hence the `?` in the regex. So someone's using it to search for ng-repeats in their html. :)

Comment: Ahh, that does make sense. I didn't even think about RegExp. Thank you for answering my question.